# Not able to find the issue in my node js code

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am using below nodejs code. both the functions are called by my chatbot so I am not able to print output on console.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/digital-assistant/tutorial-cc-dev/files/completecode.txt

the above code is perfectly working. I make my code in same line but my code is not working. Can anybody help me to debug the same. Below is my code. Both the code returning the output consumed by `restAPI` to `chatbot`.

```
'use strict';
var request = require('request');
module.exports = {
  metadata: () => ({
    name: 'ItemCost',
    properties: {
      variable: { required: true, type: 'string' },
      itemName: { required: true, type: 'string' }
    },
    supportedActions: ['success', 'failure']

  }),
  invoke: (conversation, done) => {
    const { variable } = conversation.properties();
    const { itemName } = conversation.properties();
    conversation.logger().info("Input parameter values: variable: " + variable + ", itemname: " + itemName);
    var reqUrl = "http://localhost:8080/ords/hr/rest-v3/item/Sugar";

    request(reqUrl, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        if (body.success) {
          var cost;
          conversation.logger().info("Successful conversion");
          let jsonData = JSON.parse(res.body);
          let obj = new Object(jsonData);

          obj.items.forEach(itemChild => { cost = itemChild.itemcost; });

          let result = {};
          result.itemCost = cost
          conversation.variable(variable, result);
          //conversation.reply("Hello);
          conversation.transition('success');
          conversation.keepTurn(true);
          done();
        }
        else {
          conversation.logger().warn("error type: " + body.eror.type);
          if (body.error.hasOwnProperty("info")) {
            conversation.logger().warn("error message: " + body.error.info);
          }
          conversation.transition('failure');
          conversation.logger().warn("Error code: " + res.statusCode);
          done();
        }
      }
      else {
        conversation.transition('failure');
        done();
      }
    });


  }
};
```

Comment: I recommend a more descriptive title than this. It could apply to basically any Node problem and makes it difficult for people to find this who have the same problem as you. Beyond that, I don't really understand the problem here. What does the provided code do, exactly, that makes it "working" and what about your code posted here is "not working"?  Please see [mcve] and share any errors/expected/actual behavior.

Comment: As mentioned: please ask about the single problem you are having, and pare down your code to a [mcve] accordingly. Stackoverflow is not a general help forum, and questions that can't summarize the problem, and show only the code relevant to that problem, are effectively [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. Please [edit your question](/help/how-to-ask) to explain what the problem is, what you've already tried to fix it, and show only the code relevant to your problem. SO is here to help you figure out how to _solve_ your problem, not to help figure out "what the problem is".